# How do I approximate the function?

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the unit circle $T=\{|z|=1\}$. Show that $f$ can be approximated uniformly on $T$ by a sequence of the polynomial in z if and only if $f$ has an extension $F$ that is continuous on the closed unit disk.

[image]

Can anyone suggest to me how I do the approximation of complex function?

Comment: I think that the statement requires an analytic extension to the unit disc, not a continuous one

Comment: @Conrad it is analytic on the interior of the unit disk. Can you suggest some directions?

Comment: the hypothesis implies that the Fourier series has no terms with negative powers since $\int f(e^{i\theta})e^{in\theta}d \theta=0, n \ge 1$ by analyticity and Cauchy; in particular, the Feijer sums are polynomials and they approximate $f$ uniformly on the circle; another solution as presented below is using the Abel method

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<r<1$ and define $F_r(z)=F(rz)$, for $|z| \le 1$.

Since $F$ is analytic in the interior of the unit disk, it can be uniformly approximated on compact subsets by polynomials in $z$, in particular, on $\overline{D_r}(0)$. And since $F$ is continuous on the closed unit disk, it is also uniformly continuous there, so $F_r \to F$ uniformly on the closed unit disk as $r \to 1^-$. Glueing these two pieces should give the desired approximation.